# OpenGL: Convert Screen Width To World Coordinates?

Tags: opengl, resize, coordinates

I am trying to figure out how to convert my window width to the world coordinates. As I understand it, it ranges from -1 to 1. However, internal testing has shown that at 512 width by 512 height, the coordinates go up to around 10 (assuming depth of 0).

I want to find out how I can get the x and y limit at depth 0 as the screen size changes.

Comment: That mainly depends on the projection you use. When no projection is used, then it is -1 to 1.

Comment: How to I get the kind of projection I am using? I can get the projection itself with:

GLfloat model[16]; 
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, model); 

But I am unsure how that affects what I am doing.